# Measurements from inside conductors

Tags: electrostatics, experimental-physics, conductors

We have known for some time now that when electric field is applied across any conducting shell, then electric field inside it would be zero. It also has some fantastic applications such as electrostatic shielding.

However, is it possible to know for sure that the field inside a conductor becomes zero? For example, if we place a transmitter inside a conducting shell to resolve whether the field inside shell is non-zero or otherwise, won't it disturb the field setup while transmitting the message?

In other words, is it possible to be sure about this effect for a uniform conducting shell, and similar closed-body structures?

Answer (score 1):

I did my own research (more like web search and thinking) and thought that maybe the best possible way would be to place an electret inside the conductor and then apply an electric field. If there would be any electrical field going inside the conductor then the electret would get charged. Now if the conductor could be carefully broken down to take out the electret, we would know once and for all whether electric field even of negligible magnitude penetrates the conductor or not.

Comment: If you just want to capture charges depending on a possible internal electric field, apply an external field, disconnect and then measure the charge, then you don't need an electret : a capacitor would give you just that. But in any case, you would need to assume that charges will freely flow to your electret/capacitor from the metal for your experiment to work; again that's what you want to check in the first place...

Comment: No i would not make any physical connection between the conductor and electret. I would just place it there and due to ferroelectric nature of electret it would remember if ang electric field had been applied across it

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can always imagine a means of transmitting information which is not electrical in nature (say, with sound waves from the measurement apparatus to the surface of the metal).

However, the problem would rather be finding a means of measuring the electric field without this assumption (so: no wire, to begin with...). For example : you could enter a faraday cage and wave a multimeter all around while being in a strong electric field, and check that the multimeter shows 0 consistently. However, you would implicitly assume that the wires of the multimeter are at a constant potential, which is what you want to check in the first place.

I guess you could imagine a system making use of the stark effect, for example, to measure locally the electric field. However in any appratus that I can think of, you'd be making more assumptions than you'd want...

Ultimately, the idea of free-moving charges (that one can be checked!) implies quite directly that $E=0$.

Comment: Your last idea which can be used, involves placing a charge inside the conductor to check if it moves freely; some problems like how would you send a single charge inside, keep in mind sending ionised gas or multiple ions would move under their own influence and hence would not be much useful.

Comment: Sound waves would also cause vibrations in free charges accumulated on surface and cause changes, so cant transmit msgz this way too

Comment: Well you can always measure first and send data later. However, if I'm not mistaken, sound waves at sensible frequencies travel "in" the ion lattice, not with free moving charges.

Comment: Concerning your 1st comment, if I remember well there are direct spectroscopic measurements (xps or something similar) that can give you characteristics of the conduction band. However, a simple battery is an electron source & sink. What happens when you "short" it is quite an indication of free moving charges. You can also get electrons (not plasma) with a hot cathode in vacuum.

Comment: I believe you have replied to the sound wave anomaly, so what I have been taught is that sound waves would cause vibrations in atoms or anything to be transmitted. This would as I said before make the atoms and free charges vibrate and alter obsrrvations.

Comment: what about spectroscopic measurements, how is this applicable to my question ? And how is someone supposed to set up a cathode and related set up inside a metallic shell, then use it and still make no changes in the results of required experiment ?

Comment: Spectroscopic measurements may tell you that there *are* free electrons in conductors. Stark effect will give you the electric field strength.  For the hot cathode thing, something along the lines of : take a *non-symmetrical* piece of metal, drill a hole in it, put a hot cathode in the middle, make vacuum and count electrons at various places far from the cathode. You should get a repartition that has all the symmetries of your apparatus, whatever the orientation of the metal piece.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11139/discussion-between-rijul-gupta-and-nicolas)

Answer (score 0):

well, you could build a faraday cage and go inside it to look at your instruments, no need to transfer information outside - or you could place a recording device inside.

if it's a problem for you in your mind that there is a void inside the conductor, that problem would apply on smaller scale as well, your instrument for measuring would still take some space, so you might just as well scale it up in principle.